# How do I highlight a specific event on fullcalendar v.3.1 js/c# retrieved by gotodate function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I would like to color a single event, after positioning on the week with the gotodate function. I tried with the following code, but it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/*var event_list = $('#event_list');*//*gil70l*/
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    //
    $("#btnsearch").click(function () {
        var res = $("#txtSearch").val();
        res = res.substring(0,19);
        date = moment(res, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
             
        $('.fc-event-dot[data-date="' + date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + '"]').css('background-color', '#a31a5c');
    }),
```

Update:this is the search function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id$=txtSearch]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/GetEvent") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('|')[0],
                                val: item.split('|')[1]
                                
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                     //   alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
```

Comment: How do you propose to identify the specific event to be highlighted? The requirement isn't clear. A single day can easily contain more than one event.

Comment: Thx,Adyson,I updated the post, I don't know if I answered your question

Comment: So what exactly is the process? You type a date into the search, and then the autocomplete returns a list of possible events occuring on that day, and you have to select one...is that correct? So you'd know the event ID once the user selected it. Is this related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939781/fullcalendar-3-1-0-js-c-does-not-display-the-update-dialog-after-finding-an-eve) I just commented on? It seems like they might both be about solving different parts of the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.
Now the specific date is highlighted.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
$('#d').click(function() {
  var s = $('#s').val();
  date = moment(s).format();
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', date);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- e.g. 2021-12-02 -->


<span>Serach</span>
<input type="text" id="s" />
<span>
  <button type="text" id="d">Date
  </button></span>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this code I don't change color at the event

Comment: Updated my code example. Now the selected is highlighted. Please upvote or check as answered so I will get some points. THX

Comment: Sorry,but your code highlights a range larger than the single event, and also opens the add event popup,which is not the desired behavior