# Fullcalendar 3.1.0 js/c# does not display the update dialog after finding an event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

After searching for an event successfully, I would like to open the update / delete dialog with all information filled in. But nothing happens.
I have this code in Default.aspx:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("[id$=txtSearch]").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/GetEvent") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('|')[0],
                                    val: item.split('|')[1]
                                    
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                         //   alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("[id$=hfCustomerId]").val(i.item.val);
                    date = moment(i.item.label, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                    let eventProva = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getEventById", i.item.label);
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventProva);
                    
                },
                minLength: 1
                     });  
    });  
    </script>
```

where 'i.item.label' is the event id.But nothing happens with the line `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventProva);`

Comment: This code: `let eventProva = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getEventById", i.item.label); $("#calendar").fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventProva);` simply gets an event from the calendar, and then immediately updates it on the calendar with exactly the same information it just retrieved. It doesn't change anything, so it's not surprising you don't see anything happen. It's not clear what you were trying to achieve with those lines. You mention showing a dialog box, but you have not written any code which would show a dialog box. If you want such functionality, you need to write it yourself.

Comment: I thought '$ ("# calendar"). fullCalendar (' updateEvent ', eventProva);' open a dialog on the event eventProva. Could you tell me how to open the dialog on the chosen event?

Comment: Why did you think that? There is absolutely nothing in the documentation which suggests that. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/updateEvent

Comment: Anyway fullCalendar itself doesn't provide any functionality for opening dialogs. There are dozens of ways to create a dialog or a modal pop-up using Javascript and HTML. There are free JS/jQuery plugins available which can make it easier, or you can just write your own custom code - all you really need to do is display a div with a form in it. It's entirely up to you what you use, you need to search around and find an option you like. Then you need some JS code to get the data from the fullCalendar getEvent function and populate it into the fields in your dialog.

Comment: Ok,Thx,I will do so.